# mysql.service failed to start - MySQL system database not found in /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql

I get this error message when trying to start the MySQL service and examining its status in `systemctl`:

[image]

What is the problem and how can If ix it?

Comment: The answer on what to do is already in your image. And please do not make images. Copy/paste the text into the question.

Comment: @SYN No the folder is there but the database isn't initialized yet. OP should run `sudo mysqld --initialize` as suggested.